# docker nginx proxypass to apache no virtualhost match

Tags: docker, apache, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

Hi I have a docker setup : an nginx proxy with ports 80 and 443 exposed on my docker machine which passes all requests to Second container "apache2fpmcontainer" with port 81 binded to its own 80

Here's the nginx conf:

```
upstream domain.fr {
    server apache2fpmcontainer:81;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name domain.fr www.domain.fr;
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /tmp/acme_challenge;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://domain.fr;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
    }
}
```

Here's the apache conf:

```
DocumentRoot /home/notset/
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.fr
  DocumentRoot /home/domain.fr/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost domain.fr:80>
  ServerName domain.fr
  DocumentRoot /home/domain.fr/
</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is any request lands in the /home/notset/ document root ..
If I stop the nginx and bind back port 80 to apache, the expected behaviour is perfect ..

Do anyone has a single clue, idea, notice or enlightment why won't it acknowledge the virtualhost ?
Server variables such as http_host and server_name are correct : domain.fr

Thanks in advance :)